# Access properties of Entities

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm getting all active countries via the service id `country.repository`

```
public function getCountries(Context $context): EntityCollection
{
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('active', true));

    return $this->countryRepository->search($criteria, $context)->getEntities();
}
```

This gives me this CountryCollection:
[image: CountryCollection]

How can I access each element to get the `id` and the `name`?

I tried to loop over

```
public function test($context): array
{
    $countryIds = $this->getCountries($context);

    $ids = [];
    foreach ($countryIds as $countryId) {
        $ids[] = $countryId['id'];
    }
    return $ids;
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work. It gives this error:

> Cannot use object of type Shopware\Core\System\Country\CountryEntity
> as array

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in the ids of the countries you can use

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('active', true));

$ids = $this->countryRepository->searchIds($criteria, $context)->getIds();
```

`searchIds()` will only return the ids of the entities and not all of their properties, the benefit is that not all values have to be loaded from the DB and hydrated, therefore `searchIds()` is faster then the normal `search()`.

Comment: Thx, but that is not what I need. I need the id as well as the name or iso or basically any property within the id. Actually id is also a property within the id (see above). Thx again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function like this

```
public function test($context): array
{
    $countries = $this->getCountries($context);
    $ids = [];
    foreach ($countries as $country) {
        $ids[] = $country->getId();//or $country->getName()
    }
    return $ids;
}
```

Usually you need to open the entity file. In your case it is CountryEntity.php to check the function to get the id or other fields there.

Comment: haha I'm not sure too. I think it's the shopware way too. You can simply do $ids[$country->getId()] = $country->getName(); and you will receive the array of countries :P